# Values in dropdownlist is displayed in reverse order

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA program using worksheet change event, when the user selects the financial year its corresponding months needs to be displayed in dropdownlist (ex. from Apr20 to Mar21).

But in dropdownlist, year is displayed first followed by month(20-Dec) but my requirement is month to be displayed first then year(Dec-20). How to fix this.

```
Set monthrange = ws1.Range(Cells(Target.Row, ws1.Range("CO9:CO9").Value), Cells(Target.Row, _ ws1.Range("CP9:CP9").Value))

splittings = ws1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value

splitting(1) = Mid(splittings, 3, 2)

splitting(2) = Mid(splittings, 6, 2)


validationString = "Apr" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "May" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Jun" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Jul" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Aug" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Sep" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Oct" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Nov" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Dec" & splitting(1) & ", " & _
                   "Jan" & splitting(2) & ", " & _
                   "Feb" & splitting(2) & ", " & _
                   "Mar" & splitting(2)
                   
With monthrange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:=validationString
End With
```

Comment: This is an interesting one. I tested it and I get the same. Excel seems to be implicitly converting "Apr20" (there is no "-" in your code) to a date 20-Apr. The question is what do you want to do with the value after it has been selected? Do you want it as a string (ie "Apr-20") or do you want it as a Date (so that you can use it somewhere else)? A quick & dirty way is to use "Apr-2020, May-2020,..." in your validation string.

Comment: I want it as a string. The years are dynamic which changes based on current date and year. So i cant hardcode it. I tried with "-" between month and year, still the same issue.

Comment: Can you give an example of the “splitting” input string (from which you get your years)?

Comment: Splittings="FY20-21" where splitting(1) = Mid(splittings, 3, 2) is 20 and              
                                            splitting(2) =  Mid(splittings, 6, 2) is 21.

Comment: Do you have any years prior to 2000? If not you can use "Apr-20" & splitting(1) etc to create "Apr-2020". The issue is that Excel is "helpfully" converting the string "Apr20" to the date 20th April 2020 (as we are in 2020 now) etc (so "Mar21" also converted to 21st March 2020). A halfway workaround: if your validation string is "'Apr20,'May20, etc" ... note single quote mark "'" in front of each month, you will see just Apr20 in the cell (but the single quotes will appear in the text in the dropdown list).

Comment: No, i don't have years prior to 2000, i will try. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226042/discussion-between-sandy-and-ds-london).